# XML Pop Up from GridView LinkButton click

Tags: asp.net, xml, gridview

I have a DataGrid in which I have 3 link buttons. If I click the link button it has to fetch data from db and then populate it in an `xmldocument` object and then the xml has to be opened as a seperate window. I have done it till forming xmldoc object, I need to just open the xml without saving in my machine and it should be opened in a new window. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a handler (ashx) file and write the xml to the response stream setting the response header content-type to text/xml (important for FF and chrome).

Then implement the onclick-event for the grid link to do like this in javascript:

```
window.open('http://urltothesite/myhandler.ashx?param1=value...&paramN=valueN');
```